# how do i hook up the date with the correct api? I want the date to be uploaded to the database

Tags: android-studio

I tried connecting the date I created with various methods, such as retrofit but the response : End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ that appears is always on failure, can anyone help me solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqCWc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd01D.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.